# Suppose that $\Sigma \vdash \exists x \theta$. Do we then have that $\Sigma \vdash \theta$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is a problem from [A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://milneopentextbooks.org/download/friendly-intro-2e-update19-pdf/) by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen which is in Page number 65.

---

**Here's my attempt:**

Consider a structure $\mathfrak{U}$ and suppose that its universe is $A=\{ 1,2 \}$. Consider $\Sigma$ be the singleton consisting of the formula $\exists x(x=y)$. Then $\Sigma \vdash \exists x(x=y)$ and suppose that we had $\Sigma \vdash x=y$. Then by Soundness Theorem, $\Sigma\models x=y$.

Consider the variable assignment function $s$ into $\mathfrak{U}$ which sends $x$ to $1$ and $y$ to $2$. Then clearly, $\mathfrak{U}$ satisfies $\exists x (x=y)$ with the assignment $s$ as $\mathfrak{U}$ satisfies $x=y$ with the substituition $s[x|2]$. But on the other hand, $\mathfrak{U}$ does not satisfy $x=y$ with the substituition $s$. This would contradict that $\Sigma\models x=y$. Hence, it cannot be that $\Sigma \vdash x=y$.

---

Is this counterexample correct? Is there a way to do without appealing to the **Soundness Theorem**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your counterexample works.

As to avoiding soundness: it's difficult, although of course not impossible, to avoid the soundness theorem when proving *non*-instances of $\vdash$. This is because the definition of $\vdash$ is a "positive inductive" one - it's set up to be very easy to prove instances of $\vdash$, but that has a cost. To see the issue, think about proving $\top\not\vdash\perp$; although blindingly obvious, this isn't actually easy *(depending on what definition of "$\vdash$" you're using anyways)*.

Broadly speaking, in order to prove $\Phi\not\vdash\psi$ you need to produce a set of formulas $\Theta$ which is closed under $\vdash$, contains $\Phi$, and does not contain $\psi$ (and verify that of course). The soundness theorem is really just a way of repackaging this task: every structure $\mathfrak{M}$ has its associated **theory** $Th(\mathfrak{M})$, which is closed under $\vdash$ by soundness, and so we can think about structures instead of theories. However, we can totally "cut out the middleman:" you can produce an entirely syntactic description of $Th(\mathfrak{A})$, and prove the relevant properties of this, without ever actually referring to structures.

And this is in fact a worthwhile problem to tackle:

> Can you give a "structure-free" description of $Th(\mathfrak{A})$?

Even the case of quantifier-free formulas is instructive here. *(HINT: think about ways of splitting the set of free variables into two possibly empty pieces.)*